# How to dynamically add/remove linear layout in android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

So I currently have an android app that adds and removes a line of a linear layout with the push of a button. The Linear layout contains two edittexts and and two textviews but the line is added at the end of the list, and I was wondering if there is a way to  add/remove a line of the linear layout that depends on the selected edittext.

eg: I have 4 lines of linear layouts and an edittext in the 2nd line is selected, I press the add button and then a line is inserted between the 2nd and 3rd lines.
Below is my code

```
 ToggleButton timeTempToggle;
ArrayList<EditText> dataET = new ArrayList<>();

Button buttonAddStep,buttonRemoveStep;

int id=1; //the id number which indicates the number of commands that will be used


LinearLayout mainLayout; //orientation is vertical

  @Override
protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.new_parameters);
    buttonAddStep = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAddStep);
    buttonRemoveStep = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRemoveStep);
    mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);




  buttonAddStep.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
          if(id<8) {
              //adds a stage to be included (limit is 8)
              id++;
              mainLayout.addView(linearlayout(id,"","0"));
              //append after all lines
          }

      }
  });

 buttonRemoveStep.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
          if(id>1){ // removes a step from the list of steps
              //removes the stage from the thermal cycling procedure
              //will not remove the first step
              id--;
              mainLayout.removeViewAt(id);
              dataET.remove(dataET.size()-1);
              dataET.remove(dataET.size()-1);
              //remove the  last value and line
          }
      }
  });
 }
 private LinearLayout linearlayout(int _intID, String et1, String et2)
{
    LinearLayout LLMain=new LinearLayout(this);
    LLMain.setId(_intID);
        LLMain.addView(textView(_intID, String.valueOf(_intID) + " Temp (C): "));
        LLMain.addView(editText(_intID, et1));
        LLMain.addView(textView(_intID + 1, "Time(s): "));
        LLMain.addView(editText(_intID + 1, et2));


    LLMain.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    return LLMain;
}

private EditText editText(int _intID,String preset) {
    EditText editText = new EditText(this);
    editText.setId(_intID);
    editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    editText.setWidth(130);
    editText.setText(preset);
    dataET.add(editText);
    return editText;
}


private TextView textView(int _intID,String Type)
{
    TextView txtviewAll=new TextView(this);
    txtviewAll.setId(_intID);
    txtviewAll.setText(Type);
    txtviewAll.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
    return txtviewAll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can construct an ArrayList and modify it first. that way you can manage the sequence of things in the list. Once your ArrayList is in order you like, add it in a for-each loop to where you want them.

EDIT. 
1) This does mean you have to re-create your view.
2) Since max number is 8 it is not so bad. If the number is N I would not recommend this simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Visibility` of view using `void setVisibility (int visibility)`:

More [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int))

[image]